# Появляется горизонтальный скролл Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У сontainer по умолчанию стоят падинги и маргины. 
Я убираю падинги, для того, чтоб растянуть на весь экран изображение. После того как делаю `padding: 0; margin: 0` , то появляется горизонтальный скролл.

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос проблемный код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В бутстрапе нужны эти отступы для того, чтобы когда вы делите контент на колонки, между колонками было расстояние, а побокам нет. Вот окрашенный пример для наглядности:

```css
span{
  line-height:3;
  display:block;
  background:rgba(168, 0, 221, 0.5);
}
.wrapper,
.container,
.row,
.col-xs-4{
  background:rgba(0, 119, 221, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
<span>.wrapper</span>
  <div class="container">
  <span>.container</span>
 
    <div class="row">
    <span>.row</span>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><span>.col-xs-4</span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><span>.col-xs-4</span></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><span>.col-xs-4</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Горизонтальная полоса прокрутки появляется потому что `.row` имеет отрицательный `margin`. Убрав его останутся `padding` от `.col-**-*`

Если хотите убрать отступы вообще, то тогда вам нужно убрать не только `padding` у `.container`, но и `margin` у `.row` и `padding` у ВСЕХ `.col-**-*`

P.S. `margin` у `.cotainer` убирать при этом не нужно, убрав его вы сдвинете весь контент влево, если он окажется меньше экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал, крутил свой код, и попробовал это с тегом `<html>`:

```
<html lang="en" style="
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;">
```

и горизонтальная прокрутка пропадает, пользуйтесь.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте это:

- `overflow-x:hidden;` (Уберает горизонтальный )
- `overflow-y:hidden;` (Уберает вертикальный)
- `overflow:hidden;` (Уберает все)

Comment: Скорее всего, это лечение симптома, но не причины

Comment: С overflow нужно быть осторожным, должна быть 100% уверенность, что внутри этого контейнера не будет всплывающих окон, и прочих выпадающих, появляющихся элементов. Это свойство их обрежет или не покажет вовсе.

Comment: Да, вы правы, но без примера кода сложно что-то советовать, поэтому как есть. :)