# Для чего нужен отрицательный margin и положительный padding в bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap, padding, margin, grid-layout

Bootstrap'ом редко пользовался, как-то не вникал в эти положительные и отрицательные отступы блоков.

Подскажите, для чего в блоке `.container` положительный padding, а в блоке `.row` отрицательный margin? Какая практическая польза в этих отступах?

Comment: Похожий вопрос уже был - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668124/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB-bootstrap/668146#668146

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это сделано для выравнивания.

У каждой колонки слева и справа есть `padding`, равный `15px`. Он нужен для генерации одинакового отступа между колонками. Однако в этом случае отступ слева у первой и отступ справа у последней колонки в строке **складывается** с отступами контейнера.

Чтобы нивелировать его используется `.row` с отрицательным `margin` равным `15px`. Если использовать `.row`, то левый отступ у первого столбца и правый отступ у правого столбца "проваливаются" в уже существующие отступы у контейнера и не занимают дополнительного места.

На вопрос почему бы не убрать отступ у контейнера и отказаться от отрицательного `margin` у `.row` ответ простой: блоков с контейнером может быть несколько, и в одном из них может отсутствовать сетка.

Чтобы блоки с сеткой и без нее были выравнены по левой и правой границе, как раз и придумали этот прием с отрицательными `margin`. А сам `padding` у контейнера еще нужен и для того, чтобы его содержимое не прилипало к границе экрана на небольших разрешениях.

**update:** при многократной вложенности, в качестве контейнера выступает уже колонка, а принцип действия тот же самый.

Comment: Почти дописал ответ, но тут всплыл ваш, с тем же содержанием :) Удаляю свой, а вам плюс.

Comment: Кроме того, для адаптивности. При изменении ширины экрана нужно просто изменить ширину колонок с 25% на 33.333% или 50% или 100%.  Мой пример к другому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/690023/220220

Answer (score 3):

Отрицательный отступ у .row для того, чтобы при многоуровневой структуре не суммировались отступы у блоков разных уровней.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="outer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" id="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В приведенном примере блок #inner будет по размеру такой же как блок #outer. Если бы у row не было отрицательных отступов, то блок #inner был бы меньше блока #outer на 15px с каждой стороны.